# use local variables outside ther functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've tried this:

```
function a_function(){   
    var data = "information";      
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: A bit more code or further description of what you are trying to achieve would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. You need to create a variable outside of that scope and assign to it:

```
var data;
function a_function(){   
    data = "information";      
});
a_function();
console.log(data);
```

Another answer has been posted mentioning learning about scope. Follow that advice and try to get your head around it early, it will save you a lot of hassle in the future.

Comment: Seriously, this is programming 101.

Comment: I'm feeling generous though - we all have to start somewhere!

Comment: You don't need to declare `data` variable earlier. When you call `a_function()` `data` will become global variable automatically.

Comment: True, but I would argue that it's bad practice to do it that way

Comment: @FixerRB That is an horrendous practice only allowed in non-strict mode because of backwards compatibility reasons. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

*Technically* you can, though it's generally **not a good idea**:

```
function a_function() {
    data = "information";
}
a_function();
console.log(data);
```

The reason this works is because, by not using the `var` keyword to declare a variable, JavaScript (being the good little dynamic language that it is) is writing to the `data` property of the "current" object, which is `window`.  And, thus, globally accessible.  It's basically the equivalent of doing this:

```
function a_function() {
    window['data'] = "information";
}
a_function();
console.log(window['data']);
```

As I said, it's *generally* not a good idea.  Other approaches include returning the value:

```
function a_function() {
    var data = "information";
    return data;
}
var data = a_function();
console.log(data);
```

Or perhaps creating the value in the larger scope and setting it in the function:

```
var data;
function a_function() {
    data = "information";
}
a_function();
console.log(data);
```

Basically, in general you want to maintain scope and control flow and try to avoid "globals" where possible.

Answer (score 2):

you need to read about scope and how it work .

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#JavaScript

For example a variable declared in a function exist only in this function. Once you are outside this fonction, the variable are deleted so it is undefined

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ecapsulate `data` but use it outside of the function `a_function`, you need to return `data` and call `a_function`. Something like this should work:

```
function a_function() {
  var data = "information";
  return data;
};

var data = a_function();
```

Note, due to scope, `data` inside the function is different than `data` outside the function. If you don't create a new var named `data` outside the function, you will not be able to access `data` because it doesn't exist in the outer scope.

The following code demonstrates scope:

```
function a_function() {
  var data = "information";
  return data;
};

var data = "different information";
var data2 = a_function();
console.log(data);
console.log(data2);
```

The output from the code will yield:

```
different information
information
```

Answer (score 1):

You either have to pass the value to a variable in the scope that is shared by the console.log() call like:

```
var data;
function a_function(){   
    //note the ommission of the 'var' keyword
    data = "information";      
});
a_function();
console.log(data);
```

or you have to have the function return the value and use that as input to the log() method:

```
function a_function(){   
    var data = "information";
    return data;
}
console.log(a_function());
```

or wrap the console.log() call in a helper function that your function calls from within its scope, passing data as an argument:

```
function log(data){
     console.log(data);
}

function a_function(){   
    var data = "information";
    log(data);
}
```

EDIT: as others have mentioned, while we can tell you all the ways to do this, it is better to learn more about scope and understand why the methods people suggest work.